# How do I infill non-adjacent rows with sample data from previous rows in R?

Tags: r, random, sample

I have data containing a unique identifier, a category, and a description.
Below is a toy dataset.

```
prjnumber <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
category <- c("based","trill","lit","cold",NA,"epic", NA,NA,NA,NA)
description <- c("skip class",
                 "dunk on brayden",
                 "record deal",
                 "fame and fortune",
                 NA,
                 "female attention",
                 NA,NA,NA,NA)
toy.df <- data.frame(prjnumber, category, description)

> toy.df
       prjnumber category      description
    1          1    based       skip class
    2          2    trill  dunk on brayden
    3          3      lit      record deal
    4          4     cold fame and fortune
    5          5     <NA>             <NA>
    6          6     epic female attention
    7          7     <NA>             <NA>
    8          8     <NA>             <NA>
    9          9     <NA>             <NA>
    10        10     <NA>             <NA>
```

I want to randomly sample the 'category' and 'description' columns from rows that have been filled in to use as infill for rows with missing data. 
The final data frame would be complete and would only rely on the initial 5 rows which contain data. The solution would preserve between-column correlation.
An expected output would be:

```
> toy.df
       prjnumber category      description
    1          1    based       skip class
    2          2    trill  dunk on brayden
    3          3      lit      record deal
    4          4     cold fame and fortune
    5          5      lit      record deal
    6          6     epic female attention
    7          7    based       skip class
    8          8    based       skip class
    9          9     lit       record deal
    10        10   trill   dunk on brayden
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
complete = na.omit(toy.df)
toy.df[is.na(toy.df$category), c("category", "description")] =
    complete[sample(1:nrow(complete), size = sum(is.na(toy.df$category)), replace = TRUE),
             c("category", "description")]
toy.df
#    prjnumber category      description
# 1          1    based       skip class
# 2          2    trill  dunk on brayden
# 3          3      lit      record deal
# 4          4     cold fame and fortune
# 5          5      lit      record deal
# 6          6     epic female attention
# 7          7     cold fame and fortune
# 8          8    based       skip class
# 9          9     epic female attention
# 10        10     epic female attention
```

Though it would seem a little more straightforward if you didn't start with the unique identifiers filled out for the `NA` rows...

Comment: Exactly, that's why it was so tricky. I have Identifier slots with no data in non-contiguous rows.

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
toy.df %>%
      mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), sample(.[!is.na(.)]))), 2:3)
```

Based on new information, we may need a numeric index to use in the `funs`.

```
toy.df %>% 
   mutate(indx= replace(row_number(), is.na(category), 
           sample(row_number()[!is.na(category)], replace=TRUE)))  %>%
   mutate_each(funs(.[indx]), 2:3) %>% 
   select(-indx)
```

Comment: Added the `sample`, may be that is what needed

Comment: ...and maybe with a `replace = TRUE`. Also worth noting that this doesn't preserve correlation between the two columns. Not entirely clear if OP wants that or not.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the comment.  I am also not sure by reading the question.

Comment: Thanks for both solutions, I was looking to preserve correlation and it seems via testing that both do

Comment: @JasonMatney Do you have cases where one column has `NA` while other don't

Comment: No, all `NA` cases occur in both columns of the row

Comment: In that case, Gregor's solution would be correct, right?

Comment: @akrun Updated solution gives a Warning message but is successful:
`In replace(1:2136, is.na(c(22L, 16L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27L, 4L, 17L,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: Need that `replace = TRUE` in the sample ;)

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, I didn't test it carefully

Comment: Well, the example had 5 filled and 5 missing rows, easy to miss.

Answer (score 2):

Using Base R to fill in a single field a at a time, use something like (not preserving the correlation between the fields):

```
fields  <-  c('category','description')
for(field in fields){
    missings  <-  is.na(toy.df[[field]])
    toy.df[[field]][missings]  <-  sample(toy.df[[field]][!missings],sum(missings),T)
}
```

and to fill them in simultaneously (preserving the correlation between the fields) use something like:

```
missings  <-  apply(toy.df[,fields],
                    1,
                    function(x)any(is.na(x)))

toy.df[missings,fields]  <-  toy.df[!missings,fields][sample(sum(!missings),
                                                           sum(missings),
                                                           T),]
```

and of course, to avoid the implicit for loop in the `apply(x,1,fun)`, you could use:

```
rowAny <- function(x) rowSums(x) > 0
missings  <-  rowAny(toy.df[,fields])
```